# Items from Observable<Type> don't have functions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm getting ojects via HTTPClient into an `Observable`, so my `getTasks()` function return an `Observable<Task[]>`.

```
this.taskList = this.taskService.getTasks()
.pipe(
    map( list =>
        list.filter(t => console.log(t)) 
    )
);
```

If I log every `Task`, I notice that these objects are not real `Task` objects as if I have built them with a constructor: e.g. they don't have getter functions I defined in the class.

Is this the expected behavior?
If so, must I construct every object with the `map` operator?

Comment: This is expected, and yes you need to one way or the other make instances of your class :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `Observable<Task[]>` is just a type guard for TypeScript. When compiled to JavaScript this means nothing and your response is just a plain JavaScript object that probably comes from `JSON.parse`.

So for example you can do these depending on what `Task` is.

```
this.taskList = this.taskService.getTasks()
  .pipe(
    map(list => list.map(task => new Task(task))),
  );
```

or using `Object.assign`:

```
this.taskList = this.taskService.getTasks()
  .pipe(
    map(list => list.map(task => Object.assign(new Task(), task))),
  );
```